# .NET Collections and Accessing Object Methods

Tags: c#, collections

I'm completely new to GUI programming and need a little help with a list of pictureboxes.

The idea is that I have a list of pictureboxes. When a user clicks on one I want to (for example) change the BorderStyle property of the one selected to be Fixed3D, but change the remaining collection borders to FixedSingle (or something like that). What's the proper way to do something like this? I guess the bigger picture is how do I get a method of one class to call a method of another without having any information about it?

```
class myPicture
{
  private int _pictureNumber;
  private PictureBox _box;
  public myPicture(int order)
  {
    _box = new List<PictureBox>();
    _box.Click += new System.EventHandler(box_click);
    _pictureNumber = order;
  }
  public void setBorderStyle(BorderStyle bs)
  {
    _box.BorderStyle = bs;
  }
  public void box_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //here I'd like to call the set_borders from myPicturesContainer, but I don't know or have any knowledge of the instantiation
  }
}

class myPicturesContainer
{
  private List<myPicture> _myPictures;
  //constructor and other code omitted, not really needed...
  public void set_borders(int i)
  {
    foreach(myPicture mp in _MyPictures)
      mp.setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.FixedSingle);
    if(i>0 && _MyPictures.Count>=i)
      _MyPictures[i].setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.Fixed3d);
  }
}
```

Comment: It very much depends on what UI framework you're using. In WPF, for example, you'd do it with property bindings and styles (and possibly templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a `Clicked` event in your `myPicture` class and raise that event when it is clicked.  Then you will need to attach to this event in your `myPicturesContainer` for each instance of `myPicture` that you have.

Here is a *very* simple example of what I mean:

```
class myPicture
{
    public event Action<Int32> Clicked = delegate { };

    private int _pictureNumber;

    public void box_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Clicked(this._pictureNumber);
    }
}

class myPicturesContainer
{
    private List<myPicture> _myPictures;

    public void set_borders(int i)
    {
        foreach (myPicture mp in _myPictures)
        {
            mp.Clicked += pictureClick;
        }
    }

    void pictureClick(Int32 pictureId)
    {
        // This method will be called and the pictureId
        // of the clicked picture will be passed in
    }
}
```